Problem with the (R) encoding on the Privileges page
On the privileges page, the reg glyph isn't appearing correctly, it's double escaped or similar:

&amp;#174;


@JoeWreschnig I know, but last time I mentioned something like that I was reminded that we've not yet finalised the name ;) I thought I'd just ask for the (R) symbols to be fixed first.

@shog9 Cheers :)

Also appears on the mobile version of the site

@Ambo100 I'd not noticed that, even with all my mobile browsing - might need to add it as a new issue however?

@Zhaph-BenDuguid: It appears to have been fixed

Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113026/lego-is-broken-in-the-se-site-directory

Now fixed; thanks for the report!

Cheers good to have an accepted answer to go with the status completed tag :)
